# pluck up vs gain vs get

Tags: phrase-choice

What's the difference between the following sentences:

> 1 He finally plucked up enough courage to ask her to marry him.

> 2 He finally gained enough courage to ask her to marry him.

> 3 He finally got enough courage to ask her to marry him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pluck up courage" is indeed a very common expression in the UK. According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pluck) *To pluck up "summon up" (courage, heart, etc.) is from c. 1300.*

It suggests he made some effort. He steeled himself, or at least pulled himself together. Perhaps "he psyched himself up [to do something]" is a more recent equivalent.

In your other two sentences, whether he finally *gained* enough courage or *got* enough courage, he doesn't seem to have made any effort. Perhaps he just waited, or had a stiff drink.

By the way, I've never heard "plucked up *enough* courage". The expression is usually unmodified.

Comment: @coolguy: I've just added a last line to my answer, fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

The term "plucked up", which I don't ever recall hearing as a native US English speaker, may be a regional saying or more common in the UK or another non-US English dialect.  But it does appear in the online dictionary at:

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pluck%20up)

as:

> 1. to assume an appearance of : bring to the fore : SUMMON
>    *plucked his nerve up to demand an explanation*
> 2. to eradicate by or as if by tearing up by the roots

Versions 2 and 3 are much more common and both would be more likely to be used in ordinary conversation.